# bin_search return an array with 15 elements in C++

Tags: c++

I would like to create an array `i_array` with 15 elements and rate every element with formula

```
a = sin((Pi * (i - 7)) / 15)
```

and return it.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

void sinuss(double (&arr)[15]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
        arr[i] = std::sin((M_PI * (i - 7)) / 15);
        std::cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

void modBinSearch(double arr[], double start, double end){


    if (start > end){
        return -1;
    }
    const int mitte = start +((end-start)/2);
    if(arr[mitte] == 0.0){
        return mitte;
    }
    else if(arr[mitte] > 0.0){
           return modBinSearch(arr[], start, mitte-1);
        }
    return modBinSearch(arr, mitte+1,end);


}

int main() {
    double i_array[15];
    sinuss(i_array);
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
        std::cout << i_array[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    int arr[] = sinuss(i_array);
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int result = modBinSearch(arr, 0, n-1);
    return 0;
}
```

I have no idea. I don't know what my error is.

I am new in C++, because it I have a lot of problem with it:(

In my function sinuss() I should return rated elements as array and in function modBinSearch() I should return the least element who  not smaller as 0.0 is. But my programm is wrong :(

Comment: This should not be tagged with c#

Comment: Where is the memory declared for the returned data?  You can't return an array to a pointer from a function.  A function variables a placed on the execution stack.  When you return from a function the stack variables are disposed and no longer exist.  So you have to declare the memory for the array in the main so the data is copied on the return from the method before the data is disposed.

Comment: That sould not be tagged with C either.

Comment: thank you. I am new in programming.:( So I changed my code. Do you mean so?

Comment: there is no point in `#include`ing `<cmath>` **and** `<math.h>`

Comment: mmh, I cannot understand how(

Comment: I got hexadecimal as output. And there are not in array..:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a type of what you desire. Suggesting a `std::array<double,15>`. It makes coding what you want more natural.

```
    #include <array>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>

    using namespace std;

    using ArrOf15Dbl = array<double, 15>;

    ArrOf15Dbl sinuss() {
        ArrOf15Dbl i_array;

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {

            i_array[i] = sin((M_PI * (i - 7)) / 15);
            cout << i_array[i] << ' ';
        }
        cout << '\n';
        return i_array;
    }

    int main() {
        ArrOf15Dbl x = sinuss();
        for (auto i : x) {
            cout << i << ' ';
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
```

But returning arrays from a function is not possible with C++98/03. So one solution is to allocate the needed memory dynamically, but don't forget to release it later!

```
    #include <cmath>
    #include <cstddef>
    #include <iostream>

    int const kArrSiz = 15;

    // OBS: caller assumes ownership of array pointer!
    // Must be deleted with "delete [] foobar;"
    double* sinuss() {
        double* i_array = new double[kArrSiz];

        for (int i = 0; i < kArrSiz; ++i) {

            i_array[i] = std::sin((M_PI * (i - 7)) / kArrSiz);
            std::cout << i_array[i] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
        return i_array;
    }

    int main() {
        double* x = sinuss();
        for (int i  = 0; i < kArrSiz; ++i) {
            std::cout << x[i] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
        delete [] x;
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

But with a change of interface to your function, it can be made safer by requiring the caller to allocate the array and your function instead fills it with your required values.

```
    void sinuss(double (&arr)[15]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
            arr[i] = std::sin((M_PI * (i - 7)) / 15);
            std::cout << arr[i] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    int main() {
        double i_array[15];
        sinuss(i_array);
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
            std::cout << i_array[i] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: mmh, I didn't understand your code. If I copy and pasta,there are a lot of errors

Comment: @KG.Boys What compiler are you running and with which version of C++ are you trying to use?

Comment: I use GCC, and  gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) 4.8.4

Comment: So, thank you. The second one works ,  I got in output all elements, but I need it as array, because I must write my second function , so that I can use this array in my second function. :(

Comment: @KG.Boys There *is* partial C++11 support in gcc 4.8.2. You might want to try and add `-std=gnu++0x` to the compile command.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, it worked,  I edited my Code, could you look it please

Comment: Don't know if this explains anything: 
`/*    int arr[] = sinuss(i_array); will not works since sinuss has no return value */
/*    int const willNotWork = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); will not work since size of arr unknown */
    double *smallestButBiggerThanZero = std::upper_bound(i_array, i_array + n, 0.0);
    if (smallestButBiggerThanZero == i_array + n) {
        std::cout << "No value is bigger than zero\n";
    }
    std::cout << "The value you are looking for is " << *smallestButBiggerThanZero << '\n';
    return 0;
}` This assumes i_array is sorted.

Comment: mmh, when I use return in function sinuss(), it didn't work..:(

Answer (score 1):

There are usually better ways to write loops that use a sequence of floating-point values, such as using an integer for loop control and calculating the floating-point value from the integer in each iteration. (Alternatively, you can use a floating-point object for loop control but take care to use only integer values for the loop expressions.)